# Two column Algorithmicx with variable-width columns

Tags: two-column, multicol, algorithmicx

In [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154725/1347), @Jubobs suggested to use the `multicol` package around an `algorithmic` environment, to typeset the algorithm in two columns.

Recently, I faced a rather aesthetic issue: It might be the case that one column has a long line, while all lines in the other column are short. Example:

[image: An algorithm with a long line]

Here's the code for the above picture:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[width=11cm]{geometry}   % page width is reduced to show the effect
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}[t]
    \caption{An algorithm with a long line.}
    \label{alg1}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \If{$(x = y^2+1$ and $z=x^3+4y -12)$ }
                \State $a \gets b + c$
            \EndIf

            \columnbreak

            \State $x \gets 0$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{multicols}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to typeset an `Algorithmicx` environment in two columns, but with unequal widths? I tried the `vwcol` package as suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89762/1347), but I wasn't able to make it work for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this be what you seek? The proposed solution uses `varwidth` package. Since `algorithmic` environment is wrapped inside the `varwidth`, `algostore` and `algorestore` is used to continue the numbering.

Note the `xx\linewidth` can be used to change the width of `varwidth`

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[width=11cm]{geometry}   % page width is reduced to show the effect
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{algorithm*}[t]
    \caption{An algorithm with a long line.}
    \label{alg1}
    \begin{varwidth}[t]{0.45\textwidth}        % change 0.45 to suit your need
       \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \If{$(x = y^2+1$ and $z=x^3+4y -12)$ }
                \State $a \gets b + c$
            \EndIf
           \algstore{myalg}
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{varwidth}\quad\quad\quad              % the gap between columns
 \begin{varwidth}[t]{0.4\textwidth}            % change 0.4 to suit your need
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
             \algrestore{myalg}
             \State $x \gets 0$
  \end{algorithmic}
  \end{varwidth}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can set simply `\textwidth` in both `varwidth`. The width is determined by its contents. I think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Karl. But for the first one, I used it to mimic the OP's image, showing that one has some options. For automation, yes, the contents determine the width. Thanks for bringing that up.