# Divide a algorithm with small sub parts in more than one page

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I want to write down a algorithm using TeXStudio. The algorithm is very huge so it cannot fit in one page. I use `\usepackage{algorithm}` ,`\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}` to write down this algorithm. I have a demo code here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $i\gets 10$
\If {$i\geq 5$} 
    \State $i\gets i-1$
 \Else
  \If {$i\leq 3$}
        \State $i\gets i+2$
     \EndIf
\EndIf 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to write down

```
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $i\gets 10$
\If {$i\geq 5$} 
    \State $i\gets i-1$
 \Else
```

Upto this portion in one page and rest of the portion into another page.

```
    \If {$i\leq 3$}
        \State $i\gets i+2$
     \EndIf
\EndIf 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

This portion is in another page.

I saw various example in stack exchange which define this problem but I cannot understand how this works. So if anyone help me to divide my example into two pages it is good for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your demo code compilable adding the `\documentclass` and all the necessary `\usepackage`s.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204703/multicols-not-breaking-procedures-in-algorithm2e/204792?s=1|12.2582#204792

Comment: Even though the suggested duplicate uses `algcompatible`, it should work with `\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}`.