# ConTeXt: Is there a way to create multi-page code listings?

Tags: floats, context, split, lstlisting

I am using t-vim module and I would like to format my listings similar to figures with captions, but with the ability to spread them over multiple pages. I can see three ways to do it:

- Put the \typeCfile{mycode.c} command inside a float object. The problem is that floats cannot be split over multiple pages.
- Type the listing as text and add a caption after it. However, my listings are sometimes split by figures and I did not find a way to prevent a float object from entering my listings.
- Put each line of code inside a row of an invisible table and make the table to be splitable. Unfortunately, I did not find a way to automatically create such a table out of my source file.

Is there any other solution or can one of my solutions be fixed?

Comment: KOMA supports a \FloatBarrier.  You can also do it using \setcounter{topnum}{0} and \setcounter{bottomnum}{0} temporarily.  You would need a \clearpage to stop [p] floats.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204703/multicols-not-breaking-procedures-in-algorithm2e/204792?s=1|27.3059#204792

Comment: Also, \afterpage (afterpage package} runs to completion before the first float.

Comment: @John Kormylo : you are not using a ConTeXt syntax. The wiki recommands \definenumber and \setnumber[][]. I do not know wether KOMA scripts are ConTeXt compatible.

Comment: I asked on the mailing list.  Here is your answer: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/093069.html

Comment: @henri-menke , thank you for your reply. I tried the solution from the mailing list, but noticed the same problems as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455484/context-is-there-a-way-to-create-multi-page-code-listings/455711#comment1146971_455711).

Comment: How about this: `\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable}`?

Answer (score 8):

By default only tables can be broken across pages when you put them in a float block. With ConTeXt version `2018.10.18 00:07` a new environment with the name `splittext` was added which can be used to create multipage floats for other text based content, e.g. code listing.

To create such a multipage float you have to put your text in the `splittext` environment.

```
\setuppapersize [A6] [A5,landscape]

\setuparranging [2SIDE]

\showframe [page]

\definefloat [listing]

\starttext

\startplacefloat [listing] [location={split},title={Dummy listing}]
  \startsplittext
  \dorecurse{35}{Line \recurselevel\endgraf}
  \stopsplittext
\stopplacefloat

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get `Listing 1 (cont)` or something similar on the 2nd page?

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works, but for some reason figures can still break the listing parts: [Example1](https://i.imgur.com/6BDc0tf.png). Moreover, small listing parts can occupy whole page, which is also kind of a problem: [Example2](https://i.imgur.com/4j6EJNa.png). Is there a way control this behavior?

Comment: @Goshik: For `Example 2`, why use a `split` if you have a small listing. Is this in an automated workflow?

Comment: @Aditya: That small listing is a part of the big one. Even if it was a separate one, it would be convenient to use the same code for all listings, since you never know in advance how long each of them is.