# Long Algorithm in a Double-Column Paper

Tags: algorithm2e

I wrote a long algorithm in a double-column paper. The issue that we have here is the length of the algorithm that exceeds the paper. Is there any solution to help me for that?

Appreciate it

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\ IncMargin{1em}
 \begin{algorithm}
\SetKwData{Left}{left}\SetKwData{This}{this}\SetKwData{Up}{up}
\SetKwFunction{Union}{Union}\SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\Input{$\mathcal{G}_{1}$,$\mathcal{G}_{2}$,$\mathcal{G}_{g}$, $\eta_{I}^C$, $\eta_{1}^C$,$\eta_{2}^C$,$\eta_{G}^C$,$\boldsymbol \Psi$,U}
\Output{$\hat {\textbf{s}}_{g}$, $g=2,3,...,G$}
\BlankLine
\emph{Initialize: $j=0,q=1$,$\hat {\textbf{s}}_{g}={0}_{N \times k_{g}}$,$\varepsilon$}\

\For{$k < k_1$}{
\ $k=k+1$

\ Initialize $l=1$

\ $ \textbf{r}_1=\textbf{Y}^{cs}_1 (:|k)$

\While{$   \|\textbf{r}_{l} \|^{2}> \eta_{I}     $}{
\ $ \psi=argmax_{(i=1,2,.,N)} (\boldsymbol \Psi^H (:|i)\textbf{r}_l)$
\ $\mathcal{B}_l=\{\psi+j|-U+1<j<U-1\}$
\ $\Sigma\mathcal{B}_{k}=\bigcup\limits_{p=1}^{\l} \mathcal{B}_p$
\ $l=l+1$
\ $\textbf{r}_l=(\textbf{I}-\boldsymbol \Psi(:|\Sigma \mathcal{B}_k) \boldsymbol \Psi^{\dagger} (:| \Sigma \mathcal{B}_k) ) \textbf{Y}^{cs}_{1} (:|k)$
}
}
\For{$ g<G $}{
\ $g=g+1$

\ $v= \mathcal{G}_g (1) $

\ $d= \mathcal{G}_g (1) $ 

\For{$ v<\mathcal{G}_g (\mathcal{G}_g |)         $}{

\ $v=v+1$

\For{$ d<\mathcal{G}_g (\mathcal{G}_g | |)$}{

\ $d=d+1$

\ $ \{\textbf{A}^g_{(v|d)}\}=\Sigma \mathcal{B}_k \cap \Sigma \mathcal{B}_d $

\ $ [\textbf{Z}^g_{(v|d)}]=|[\textbf{A}^g]_{(v|d)} |$

\  $\textbf{R}^g_{(v|d)}=(\textbf{I}-\boldsymbol \Psi(:|\textbf{A}^g_{(v|d)}) 
\boldsymbol \Psi^{\dagger} (:| \textbf{A}^g_{(v|d)}) ) \textbf{Y}^{cs}_{g}$

\If{$ d<\mathcal{G}_g (\mathcal{G}_g | |)$}{

\   $[\textbf{N}^g_{(v|d)}]=  ||\textbf{R}^g_{(v|d)}||_F^2$

}

}


}
\ $ \Gamma ^g=\{ d,v |   [N^g_{(v|d)}] <min⁡(N^g )\times\varepsilon\}$
\ $ \Omega^g=\{\textbf{A}^g (z)  |\hspace{0.2 cm}   z=  min⁡(\textbf{Z}^g [\Gamma^g ])  \}$

\If{$ g>1 $}{

\   $\Omega^g=  \Omega^g $\backslash$  w^g $ 

}
\ $
\small{\textbf{C}^g=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  {\Omega^g (1)+j | 0\leq j\leq(U-1) } \\
   \vdots & \\
   {\Omega^g (|\Omega|-(U-1))+j | 0\leq j\leq(U-1) }
\end{array}
\right]
}$

\ $
\small{\textbf{p}^g=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  ||(\textbf{I}-\boldsymbol \Psi(:|\textbf{C}^g_{(1|:)}) 
\boldsymbol \Psi^{\dagger} (:| \textbf{C}^g_{(1|:)}) ) \textbf{Y}^{cs}_{g}||_F^2 \\
   \vdots & \\
  ||(\textbf{I}-\boldsymbol \Psi(:|\textbf{C}^g_{(|\Omega|-(U-1)|:)}) 
\boldsymbol \Psi^{\dagger} (:| \textbf{C}^g_{(|\Omega|-(U-1)|:)}) ) \textbf{Y}^{cs}_{g}||_F^2
\end{array}
\right]

}$

\ $
\small{\textbf{W}^g=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \textbf{C}^g _{(m,:)}  ;\textbf{C}^g _{(m+1,:} );...;\textbf{C}^g _{(H,:)}   | \textbf{p}^g_m=min⁡(\textbf{p}^g ),\textbf{p}^g_H=max⁡(\textbf{p}^g)\\

\end{array}
\right]
}$

\ $Initialize: t=0$

\While{$  ||R||^2_{F}> \eta_{g}^C   $}{
\ $\textbf{W}^g=\{\textbf{W}^g_{(1,:)},\textbf{W}^g_{(2,:)},...,\textbf{W}^g_{(|\Omega|-(U-1)-t|:)}\}$

\  $\textbf{R}=(\textbf{I}-\boldsymbol \Psi(:|\textbf{W}^g) 
\boldsymbol \Psi^{\dagger} (:| \textbf{W}^g) ) \textbf{Y}^{cs}_{g}$

\ $t=t+1$


}
\ $L = ||R||_F^2$

\ $\mathcal{U}_{g}=\{ E=1,……,|w^g | \hspace{0.2 cm} |\hspace{0.2 cm}||(\textbf{I}-\boldsymbol \Psi_{(:|(\textbf{W}^g $\backslash$ \textbf{W}^g(E)} )\boldsymbol \Psi^{\dagger}_{(:|(\textbf{W}^g$\backslash$ \textbf{W}^g(E)} ) 

\w^g _(\mathcal{U}_{g})=\O 

\ w^g=w^g \cap w^1$

}
\RTB
\For {$ q < G     $}{

}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204703/multicols-not-breaking-procedures-in-algorithm2e/204792?r=SearchResults&s=1|22.1234#204792

Comment: Is this question still open ?