# How to write an algorithm as a column inside the table

Tags: tables, algorithms

Let us consider the following code and the algorithm corresponding to it

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{center}
   \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
     read current\;
     \eIf{understand}{
             go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
      }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
     }
    }
    \caption{How to write algorithms}
   \end{algorithm}
   \end{center}
   \end{document}
```

Which gives the following

[image]

I want to add running times for each step to my algorithm as shown below (for example)

[image]

So, I need to make my algorithm as a column in the table and one more column for running times of each step, how can I make my algorithm as a column inside a table?

Comment: your code does not compile. please post a complete MWE.

Comment: Seems to be related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245316/writing-algorithm-in-a-table

Comment: @Nasser I provided MWE. Now, for each step in my algorithm I want to add how many times each step is running, like in second diagram using table.

Comment: I had my compiler set to use lualatex,. Your code did not compile with it. it gives errors. It compiled with pdflatex. It is always good idea to say which compiler one uses when posting an example. Try compiling your code with lualatex and see the errors.

Answer (score 4):

I would set such an algorithm using a [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to ensure it fits the entire width of the text column, since you're adding information horizontally:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,amsmath}

\newenvironment{algorithm}
  {\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{} X}{\scshape ##1}}%
   \noindent
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{@{} >{\quad} X l l @{}}  
  }
  {\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Insertion-Sort($A$)}                      & \textit{cost} & \textit{times}             \\
  \textbf{for} $j = 2$ \textbf{to} $A.\text{length}$ & $c_1$         & $n$                        \\
  $k = A[j]$                                         & $c_2$         & $n - 1$                    \\
  \itshape // Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted                                                       \\
  \quad \itshape   sequence $A[1, \dots, j - 1]$.    & $0$           & $n - 1$                    \\
  $i = j - 1$                                        & $c_4$         & $n - 1$                    \\
  \textbf{while} $i > 0$ \textbf{and} $A[i] > k$     & $c_5$         & $\sum_{j = 2}^n t_j$       \\
  \quad $A[i + 1] = A[i]$                            & $c_6$         & $\sum_{j = 2}^n (t_j - 1)$ \\
  \quad $i = i - 1$                                  & $c_7$         & $\sum_{j = 2}^n (t_j - 1)$ \\
  $A[i + 1] = k$                                     & $c_8$         & $n - 1$
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I've made a rough copy of the expected columnar output. There are a multitude of options one can add to the process; it all depends on how many of these you want to set and whether certain things require automation or not.

Comment: the \hline doesnot work for marking lines, can we do something for that. it will just make my code as i want.

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan: You mean vertical lines?

Comment: i mean horizontal line after each row

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan: Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYNFp.png)?

Comment: exactly like this

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan: I just inserted `\hline` after every ``\\`` to achieve that output. It's pretty horrible though.

Comment: yeah it works, i am using it just for the sake of easy readability purpose. i wonder if there is any other approach to replace this.?

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan: You could alternate the background colour of the rows with a light gray, perhaps.

Comment: if its easy it may look nice, can you give me instruction on that. as i have pretty long and weird algorithms and i am not that into esthetic looks for them.